# Auth0: How do I fix a 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url, when trying to update user?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests, auth0

I'm trying to update a user in [AuthO](https://auth0.com/)

I have been refering to this [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/#!/Users/patch_users_by_id)

When I run this code from command line, it works as expected and the operation is successful:

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <management_api_access_token>" -X PATCH  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"blocked":false}' https://<my_domain>.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/users/<user_id-including-auth-provider>
```

When I run the equivalent python3.9 script locally, I also get the expected successful response:

```py
def do_this():
    user = "<user_id>"

    url = f"https://<my-domain>.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/users/{user}"

    payload = json.dumps({
      "blocked": True
    })
    headers = {
      "Authorization": "Bearer <management_api_access_token>",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }

    response = requests.request("PATCH", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    print(response.text)
```

However, when I run the python code in a lambda, I get this error:

> 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://<my_domain>.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/users/<user_id>

I tried changing
`requests.request("PATCH", url, headers=headers, data=payload)`
to
`requests.patch(url, data=payload, headers=headers)`

but still same error in lambda

I have tried switching the `user_id` from
`auth0|xxxxxx`
to
`auth0%7Cxxxxx`
but still get the same error in lambda

(`%7C` is urlencoding of the pipe "|")

Other calls I make to other management api endpoints in lambda seem to work fine, such as
`/api/v2/users-by-email`
and
`/api/v2/users`

I am working locally on MacOS, but my lambdas run in Linux.
I ran it on my Ubuntu laptop and it worked fine.

What do I need to change in my code so that it will work universally?